# Maximum Subsequence Sum

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, knapsack-problem

Given an array of integers and a threshold value, determine the maximum sum of any subsequence of the array that is less than or equal to the threshold. For all but at most 15 of the elements, either `array[i] >= 2*array[j]` or `array[j] >=2*array[i]` where `j!=i`.

`threshold` can be up to to 10^17, the length of the array can be up to `60`, and `array[i]` can be up to `10^16`.

Here `threshold` is too high, so we cannot solve it by normal knapsack method. I tried it dividing this array into three parts, then getting lists of possible sums by brute force by backtracking and then merging three lists to find result. But I think there could be a more optimal way of doing this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! From your question it sounds like you already have some working code; please add that to your question so people can more easily help. Additionally, this appears to be an optimization question rather than one about errors; those kinds of questions are better asked on the [Code Review SE site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: but you are not forced to make an array to store the available sums right (which means "size of the biggest sum stored")? Have you tried to store the sums into a map/set instead?

Comment: We can store sum in set or map but there can be 2^(length of array) sums possible .That complexity is equal to brute force solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been carefully set up so that all usual approaches will run out of space.  You have to use the hint.

Step 1, sort the array size descending then and divide it into into up to 15 "weird ones" and a chain of elements such that `b1 >= 2*b2`, `b2 >= 2*b3` and so on.

You do that by taking the largest into your chain, then sticking weird ones into the weird array until you find one half the size, add that to the chain, stick weird ones into the weird array, and so on.

Now for each of the up to 32768 subsets of the weird ones, try to figure out which subset of the rest gets you closest.  However you can use the following observation.  For any element that you have a choice about including, either it is too big to include, or it must be included.  (Because if you don't include it, then all the rest together will give you a smaller number.)  That gives you a maximum of 45 decision points to consider.

In other words

```
for each subset of weird ones:
    for each element of the chain
        If we can add this element:
            Add it to the set we are looking at
    if sum(this set) is best so far, improve our max
return the best found.
```

Comment: But complexity of this solution would be equal to brute force solution. I still cannot understand what difference those 15 elements make.Can you help?

Comment: @NavneetSachan No, it is much less.  The complexity is `O(2^a * b)` where `a` is the number of exceptional numbers and `b` is the length of the chain.  The reason is that for any given subset of the 15, you do a single pass through the chain, and then have the best possible result.  You don't have a combinatorial explosion of options from the chain.

Comment: @btilly In your solution Step-1 After sort the array, Are you building the subsequence of size 15 with condition `b1 >= 2*b2, b2 >= 2*b3`. Is this what you are trying if you can elaborate that step with example that will great help in understanding the approach

Comment: @Arpit I added more explanation.

Comment: @btilly Thanks !